# Inertia:: share Auth not Executing

Tags: php, laravel, inertiajs

I have laravel with, inertia, and vue 3. So I try to access roles for each user with `$inertia.page.props.auth.user` and I setup the ***AppServiceProvider.php*** to get only id. But i get the whole data and after checking, the `auth' => function ()` is not executing but route function is properly executed. What is happening?

```
    public function boot()
    {
        Inertia::share([

            'auth' => function () {
                return ['users' => Auth::user() ? Auth::user()->only('id', 'name') : null];
            },
            'route' => function () {
                return [
                    'name' => Route::currentRouteName(),
                ];
            },
        ]);
    }
```

Rendering the page-web.php

```
Route::get('/home', function () {
    return Inertia::render('Welcome', [
    ]);
})->name('home');;
```

Comment: Did you try to remove the `try-catch` block ?

Comment: yes. the try and catch block just to test if there some error during the execution. I removed it and put the original code